# How to rotate between images

Tags: javascript

I cannot rotate between images Can anyone help me please

```
let btnRoll = document.querySelector(".roll-dice");
let diceEl = document.querySelector(".dice");

diceEl.classList.add("hidden");
btnRoll.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let dicee = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  console.log(dicee);
  diceEl.classList.remove("hidden");
  diceEl.src = "dice-${dicee}.png";
});
```

I am generating random number and I want to display random image but it doesnt work

Comment: unrelated title and question

Comment: use back ticks instead of double quotes on your dice src